# Trying to understand inputAccessoryView approach

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, inputaccessoryview

In an iOS Objective-C app, I am trying to get a bar on top of the keyboard. I want the keyboard to get "activated" via a UITextView positioned in this bar. However I am not able to display the bar.

My understanding:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myUIView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:xxx]; // 1. Create an UIView that will serve as inputAccessoryView
    myTextView=[[UITextView alloc]init]; // 2. Create a UItextView 
    [myUIView addSubview:myTextView]; // 3. Add it to the UIView 
    [myTextfield setInputAccessoryView:myUIView]; // 4. Set the UIview as being the inputAccessoryView of the textView
    // [self.view addSubview:myUIView]; // If I do this, the view is displayed but the app crashes when tapping in the textField
}
```

However the view does not get displayed, and neither is the textView.
I tried to make the textView as subview of the main controller view, and while the textview gets displayed, the myUIView doesn't

What do I do wrong in this approach ?

Comment: can you try IQKeyboard for your accessoryView?if you trying to do like this. cllick on view & view should goes upper the keyborad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different provided solutions worked, but required my textView to be outside the inputAccessoryView.

I based my solution on the work available on this [page](https://github.com/bmancini55/iOSExamples-DockedKeyboardView), which completely fulfills my expectations.

In a nutshell, what it does is to override the inputAccessoryView function to provide an UIView built on the fly, which includes the textView.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `InputAccessoryView` correctly. You are adding the `UITextView` to the `InputAccessoryView` as subview, where your `UITextView` should be added to a `view` (like `UIViewController`'s view for instance)

You need to assign `InputAccessoryView` to the `UITextView` like you did, and that is it, when keyboard will be show your `InputAccessoryView` view will be above the keyboard area.

Check this example below on how it should be added in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 40);
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *accessoryView = [UIView new];
    accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 44);
    accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    textView.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;

    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}
```

Or Swift version

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 40)
    textView.backgroundColor = .red

    let accessoryView = UIView()
    accessoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 44)
    accessoryView.backgroundColor = .green

    textView.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView

    view.addSubview(textField)
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the Input Accessory View with a green background

[image: Example of the accessory view - green background color]

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. This works indeed better, however I have now 2 issues: 1. I need to have the textfield into the accessoryview (or at least displayed on top of, which now does't work because it goes under). 2. How to have the accessoryview displayed when keyboard is hidden ? Currently it's only displayed when keyboard is pulled up. Thanks

Comment: InputAccessoryView is only visible when the `UITextView` is editing - meaning you tapped on it and you are able to type. So you need the InputAccessoryView to be visible even when user is not typing into the `UITextView`?

Comment: Yes, when the user is not typing, the keyboard is hiding and I would like the accessoryView to stay at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Then you will have to make a custom solution, where you will listen to `UIKeyboardWillShow` and `UIKeyboardWillHide` for example, inside of a `Notification` object that is sent along with this methods you can get height of the keyboard and animate your custom view along and such...